# Make the viewController's view a NSVisualEffectsView

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsvisualeffectview

I create a new viewController on storyboard. I want that viewController's view to shown thru the window. So, as far as I understood, I have to transform that view to a NSVisualEffects view.

How do I do that using interface builder?

I already have a lot of objects on that view added using interface builder, so, it will be nice to solve that using interface builder.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can delete the view in the outline view and then add a visual effects view as the view controller's view.

2) Add a effects view as the subview of the view.

3) Change the class type of the view controller's view in the inspector window.

Options one and two will let you see the effects view in Xcode. I would recommend using option 3.

Comment: It works but there is a problem. The view I want the effect is the masterViewController's view on the left side of a splitViewController. WHen I do what you say, both the master and detail viewControllers show the effect. Why?

Comment: You asked how to change the view controllers view. If you just want the left pane, only change that view controller's view.

Comment: I just changed the left view controller vie, but both changed and the left one is now not working as before. This appears to be one of those millions of half cooked stuff of xcode. I will accept your answer. thanks.

Comment: Haha yes. The storyboard stuff for OS X is, disappointingly, not quite ready for making a complex professional app.

Comment: Man, I thought interface builder for iOS was a piece of crap but after using it 10 seconds for OSX, I want to drink the blood of 1000 goats now! Not even the documentation: try to find documentation for NSTabViewController or NSSplitViewController. I wish apple stops cramming stuff to their OSes and refine this crap. It is unberable. Xcode is a disgrace. Interface Builder is a shame. Their documentations are a pile of flaming poo.